# How to temporarily disconnect git working directory?

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a *branch* on `Git` and running a server on this branch. The files required to run the server are *only* on this branch which means that checking out master will delete these files and require a complete restart and sometimes module reinstallation (*let's just say that it takes some time to rerun again*).

I still want to pull from master and merge it to my branch but I don't want the working directory to change.

Is there a way to *disconnect the working directory* so that I can checkout master, pull, checkout my branch, merge (*all in .git folder only so far*) and then reconnect the working directory again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to checkout to master. You could simply fetch all and then merge origin/master to your branch.

```
# here you are in your branch
git fetch origin # or git fetch --all if needed, or just git fetch (check the doc)
git merge origin/master
```

Note though that your local `master` won't be updated.

Another possibility is to do the following:

```
# git fetch <remote> <sourceBranch>:<destinationBranch>
git fetch origin master:branch
```

This last snippet of code can be used as well to update your `master` (if you want to):

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

Comment: out of curiosity: wouldn't a `stash`, then switching to master and doing the merge and switching back and `pop` also work in this situation?

Comment: @Alireza The goal is not to checkout to master, otherwise, the files which are only in branch will be deleted.

Comment: That's what `git stash` and `git pop` are for. You put everything that is not committed to the side, do whatever else you like, then come back and do `git pop` and everything comes back. But the solution here works, so everything is fine. I just wanted to make sure I understood the situation.

Comment: @Alireza He cannot checkout to another branch. Am I missing something?

Comment: As I understand it, he can't because he will lose what he has done in his current branch, and he isn't in a position to commit. In this situation, he can do a `git stash` and check out to another branch, do his stuff, come back to the previous branch, and do a `git pop`, if I understood the problem correctly. You solution works and is maybe even more elegant for this situation. Stash and pop are a general solution for these situations.

Comment: @Alireza, with all due respect, I think you do not understand how git stash works. git stash is to store changes without committing them. If you then checkout to master, his files would not be in his local folder due to git stash. Also, there are no changes without committing here, git stash would stash absolutely nothing in this case.

Comment: Ahh thanks @MFnx I'm relatively inexperienced, so it may be really the case that I'm mistaken. I'll look that up and try to better understand it :)